# Highcharts using SPservices not grouping data

Tags: spservices, chart

I've been using highcharts with SPservices to chart data from tracking lists.  I'm trying to add a second identical list (expertlist2) to chart in addition to the first list (expertlist1). Below is as far as I was able to go and still have the code execute to display the graph.

The issue now is that when the second list query executes and it adds the data to the chart, the plotted column from the second list is merely plotted alongside the first. This results in the chart display a duplicate column name, each of the two displaying their respective list's data.

How can I execute this so that the data from the second list is combined with the first list before rendering the chart?

```
var chartData = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Expert'/></OrderBy></Query>",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Expert'/></ViewFields>",
        listName: "{expertlist1}",
        completefunc:

        function processData (xData, status) {
            var expertData = [];

            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                expertData.push({
                    date:       $(this).attr('ows_Date'),
                    Name:     $(this).attr('ows_Name'),
                    source:   $(this).attr('ows_Source'),
                    expert:        $(this).attr('ows_Expert')
                });
            });

            var expertData = _.groupBy(expertData, 'expert');

            _.each(expertData, function(row) {
                var locCount = row.length;

                chartData.push( {
                    name:   row[0].expert,
                    y:      locCount
                });

            });

            renderChart (chartData);

        }
    });


    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Expert'/></OrderBy></Query>",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Expert'/></ViewFields>",
        listName: "{expertlist2}",
        completefunc:

        function processData (xData, status) {
            var expertData = [];

            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                expertData.push({
                    date:       $(this).attr('ows_Date'),
                    Name:     $(this).attr('ows_Name'),
                    source:   $(this).attr('ows_Source'),
                    expert:        $(this).attr('ows_Expert')
                });
            });

            var expertData = _.groupBy(expertData, 'expert');

            _.each(expertData, function(row) {
                var locCount = row.length;

                chartData.push( {
                    name:   row[0].expert,
                    y:      locCount
                });

            });

            renderChart (chartData);

        }
    });

});

/* chart function */
function renderChart (data) {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'expertchart',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b> {point.y} Times',
            percentageDecimals: 0,
            formatter: function(){
                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage)+'%  ' + this.y +' Times';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {

                    }
                },
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Expert Count',
            showInLegend: true,
            slicedOffset: 30,
            data: data
        }]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to do it like this:

```
    var chartData = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Expert'/></OrderBy></Query>",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Expert'/></ViewFields>",
            listName: "{expertlist1}",
            completefunc:
    //ommitted for brevity

        });


        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Expert'/></OrderBy></Query>",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Expert'/></ViewFields>",
            listName: "{expertlist2}",
            completefunc:
    //ommited for brevity


        });
      //moved render to here, after both have processed the data
      renderChart (chartData);
    });

    /* chart function */
    function renderChart (data) {
        //ommited for brevity
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Eric. I just tried this, and now the chart's title appears, but the chart itself no longer renders. Any ideas?